# requiring "core" in utop gives error: Unix.Unix_error (Unix.ENOENT, "sysconf", "")

Tags: ocaml, opam, utop, ocaml-core, ocaml-dune

When I try to call `#require "core"` in `utop`, I get an error:

```
utop # #require "core";;
Exception: Unix.Unix_error (Unix.ENOENT, "sysconf", "").
Raised by primitive operation at unknown location
Called from file "toplevel/topdirs.ml", line 144, characters 10-51
```

I have a `.ocamlinit` file that looks like this in my current directory:

```
(* Added by OPAM. *)
let () =
  try Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH")
  with Not_found -> ()
;;

#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
```

What could be causing this error to happen?  It appears to be an error from Findlib?

I tried wiping away my `~/.opam` directory, rerunning `opam init`, `opam switch set 4.05.0`, and reinstalling `core` and `utop`, but this error persists.  Is it possible that I also need to reinstall `opam` itself?  I am currently using a binary version of opam-1.2.2.

I'm running Arch Linux, and I believe this error started occuring after updating all the packages on my system, but I am not sure.

I am still able to use `jbuilder` to build executables, but when running the executables, they fail with a similar error:

```
$ _build/install/default/bin/my_executable
Uncaught exception:

  (Unix.Unix_error "Illegal seek" sysconf "")

Raised by primitive operation at unknown location
```

I am pretty sure this is not an exception being cause by my code, but is similar to the error occuring in `utop`.

I have a `jbuild` file that looks like this:

```
(jbuild_version 1)

(executable
 ((name main)
  (libraries (my_library))))

(install
 ((section bin)
  (files ((main.exe as my_executable)))))
```

---

*edit*: I've tried using different versions of `opam` and the compiler, including the system compiler (which is also version 4.05.0).  Nothing seems to work.  Every combination produces the same errors as above.

Comment: This looks like a [known problem](https://github.com/janestreet/core/issues/95) with core.